# Prevent malicious attacks on PHP/AJAX websites

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a website which the user can see different product and everyone can posts comments which are retrieved/saved using ajax. First the user writes his/her comment and then clicks on send which calls a function that get's data and posts it to php page to handle the request .

I was wondering if it's possible for an attacker to send multiple requests and post multiple comments and if yes, How can I prevent these kind of attacks ?

Comment: Use captcha validation before submitting any comment

Comment: Use Google Recaptcha or CSRF.

Comment: Implement user authentication and a comments / minute limit for each user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use captcha
2. You can do a query before posting, which checks if the user is the one who is poster last on the article and if he does it arlerts him "You can't post two comments in a row".

Answer (score 0):

- Use captcha
- save users IP Address that commented and limit the number of comments per hour just with a Database Query by IP Address and 1 hour ago .